# .addClass - How to call CSS from linked css?

Tags: jquery, css

I have this piece of code and I have a simple question.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
var y_scroll_pos = window.pageYOffset;
var scroll_pos_test = 150;             // set to whatever you want it to be

if(y_scroll_pos > scroll_pos_test) {
    $( "#cssmenu" ).addClass("extend");
} else if(y_scroll_pos < scroll_pos_test) {
    $( "#cssmenu" ).addClass("contract");
}
});
```

I have linked a CSS file **( via href="css/style.css")** and I would like to use **.extend** and **.contract** from such file.

Is this possible?

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, it is. Have you tried it? What happens? What do those classes do?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5uv5U/1/

I am trying this. I figured it out. Yes, it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Just include the CSS file in your HTML.

```
<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
```

You will also need to call `.removeClass()` to remove the `extend` and `contract` class when adding the other one.

See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chopper/5uv5U/2/)

Answer (score 2):

A little correction

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var y_scroll_pos = window.pageYOffset;
    var scroll_pos_test = 150;             // set to whatever you want it to be

    if (y_scroll_pos > scroll_pos_test) {
        $("#cssmenu").addClass("extend");
        $("#cssmenu").removeClass("contract");
    } else if (y_scroll_pos < scroll_pos_test) {
        $("#cssmenu").addClass("contract");
        $("#cssmenu").removeClass("extend");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course it is. addClass is just a jquery method to add a class='' to any dom element. It doesnt create the class itself.